# mysql_num_rows replacement to recommend?

Tags: php, mysql

I read that mysql_num_rows is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. So what is best replacement by your opinion?

```
$KatalogVrstaID = $redak_katalog['KatalogVrstaID'];
$rezultat_podvrsta=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM katalog_podvrsta WHERE KatalogPodvrstaVrsta='$KatalogVrstaID' ORDER BY KatalogPodvrstaID ASC");
if (mysql_num_rows($rezultat_podvrsta)==0){ ?>
```

Comment: You should first change mysql_* functions to mysqli or PDO. Because the whole mysql_* functions will be deprecated in the coming versions.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql functions as a whole are deprecated, it is not only `mysql_num_rows`. You should switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [POD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) database library. In short all mysql_* functions are deprecated.

You can read more about picking a database API [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

[Mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) is the new library you should use. they use the same function names but instead of mysql you write mysqli.. you also need to add one more parameter which is the link.

Answer (score 1):

mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.  Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used
https://www.php.net/class.mysqli

Answer (score 1):

The only replacement is to stop using `mysql_*` altogether, because the whole library is deprecated.

PDO provides `PDOStatement::rowCount()` which you use on result objects, and MySQLi provides `mysqli_result::$num_rows` or `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use MySQLi / PDO, like the Authors above me said.
 2) I read in a book that rowCount() is not 100% reliable for Select statements in some 
    DBMS, but their are alternatives to count all rows

a) use fetchAll()  <- not recommend for large results.
b) use COUNT(*) in the Select-Statement and work with the result.