# Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in

Tags: php, deprecated

I'm currently writing a php script, however I'm having issues with the deprecated functions..

Could someone please explain how I can stop these functions from being deprecated or how to change them into current ones:

```
   function calcNumActiveGuests(){
      /* Calculate number of guests at site */
      $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS;
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      **$this->num_active_guests = mysql_numrows($result);**
   }

function calcNumActiveUsers(){
      /* Calculate number of users at site */
      $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS;
      $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
      **$this->num_active_users = mysql_numrows($result);**
   }
```

They currently give me the error `Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_num\_rows replacment to recomend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396858/mysql-num-rows-replacment-to-recomend)

Comment: I did read that article, however to me it didn't make sense the answers, so I created this one withmy code

Comment: To stop the functions from being deprecated, you will need a time machine.

Comment: The best approach would be to swap to mysqli or PDO. - And then either find a tutorial on how to use mysqli/PDO or then google each function you want to have converted, I know that for atleast mysqli the functions are almost identical in writing compared to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop functions from being deprecated (well, unless your name is *[Rasmus Lerdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf)*).

Functions get deprecated for many number of reasons, and it's advised that you understand why. If you visit the [PHP](http://php.net/) page and lookup the function that has given you a warning it generally advises you of what action to take. For example: [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for
>   more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
> - [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)
> - [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)